# How to give Placeholder for TextField of Settings Bundle (Root.plist)

Tags: ios, uitextfield, placeholder, settings.bundle, root.plist

I want to give placeholder for textfield of Settings bundle (Root.plist) is it possible?if yes how?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid currently it's not possible - I was also trying to do that but can't seem to find any working solution. If that helps, the official docs where this should be placed are [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/PreferenceSettings/Conceptual/SettingsApplicationSchemaReference/Articles/PSTextFieldSpecifier.html).